# Program won't continuously read a value from a function

Tags: raspbian, spi, c

I'm in the midst of a school project and having trouble with reading ADC values from an MCP3004. I have it done in two different ways but one of them won't work.

Using wiringPi.h and mcp3004.h, all written in C.

```
//Including necessary libraries 
#include <wiringPi.h>
#include <wiringPiSPI.h>
#include <wiringPiI2C.h>
#include <wiringSerial.h>
#include <mcp3004.h>           
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <errno.h>

//Definitions used for the MCP3008  
#define BASE 100        
#define SPI_CHANNEL 0 

//Function to read ADC value from specified channel on the MCP3008 
//Call the function, input desired channel number, returns ADC as a float 
float reading_Channel(int channel_number)
{
    int channel_read, channel_out; 

    channel_read = analogRead(BASE + channel_number);
    channel_out = channel_read;

    return channel_out; 
}

int main(void)
{
/*---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/       
    //MAIN SETUP HERE
/*---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/   
    //WiringPi setup, different than wiringPiSetup() as this uses actual Broadcom pin numbers instead of virtual pin remapping.
    wiringPiSetupGpio();

    //Initialize SPI channel with the RPi for the MCP3008.
    wiringPiSPISetup(1, 5*1000*1000);   //wiringPiSPISetup(int channel, int speed) 
    delay(50);

    //Initialize I2C channel with the RPi for the MAX517.
    int fd_1;
    if ((fd_1 = wiringPiI2CSetup(0x2c)) <0) //wiringPiI2CSetup(device ID) 
    {
        fprintf (stderr, "Unable to open serial device: %s\n", strerror (errno));
        return 1;
    }

    //Checks if WiringPi is initialized.
    if (wiringPiSetup () == -1)
        {
            fprintf (stdout, "Unable to start wiringPi: %s\n", strerror (errno));
            return 1;
        }

    //Checks if Serial communications is initialized.
    int fd;
    if ((fd = serialOpen ("/dev/ttyUSB0", 115200)) <0) 
        {
        fprintf (stderr, "Unable to open serial device: %s\n", strerror (errno));
        return 1;
        }

    //WiringPi has a built-in functionality with the MCP300X ADC. 
    mcp3004Setup (BASE, SPI_CHANNEL);

    //Declaring MCP 3008 input variables pertaining to the temperature sensor.  
    int temp;

    //Declaring MCP 3008 input variables pertaining to the potentiometer.  
    int setpoint; 
/*---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/   
    //BULK OF WORK HERE
/*---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/       
    //Looping the math/code required for readings
        while(1)
        {   
            //Math required for temperature output from ADC.
            temp = reading_Channel(0); //reads ADC value from channel 0         
            temp = ((temp/1024)*3.3); //Converts ADC value to Voltage.
            temp = ((temp*1000) - 500) / 10; //Converts Voltage to temperature.

            //Serial print to USART here. 
            delay(1000);
            serialPrintf (fd, temp); //Emulates the system printf function to the serial device.

            //Math required for potentiometer output from ADC.
            setpoint = reading_Channel(1); //reads ADC value from channel 1
            setpoint = ((setpoint/1024)*5); //Converts ADC value to Voltage.
            setpoint = (4 * setpoint + 15); //Linear conversion from Voltage to temperature range (15° - 35°). 

            //Serial print to USART here. 
            delay(1000);
            serialPrintf (fd, setpoint); //Emulates the system printf function to the serial device.

            serialFlush(fd); //Discards all data received, or waiting to be send down the given device.
        }       
}
```

When running, the math outputs as if the ADC values were 0.

Wondering why the function above wont continuously acquire the ADC value? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I can't see a question.  If you have a working version why aren't you using it?

Comment: @joan Just wondering why the function wouldn't have the same operation. As if I had multiple channels instead of 2 I wouldn't want to define so many variables and repeat existing code.

Comment: Why don't you post a complete program?  I'm not going to guess why a part of a program doesn't do what you expect.

Comment: @joan Sorry about that, edited to post the entire program now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can't be right:

```
int temp;
...
temp = ((temp/1024)*3.3);
```

The rules of integer division say that any value below 1024 divided by 1024 is zero.

Try using floats for the math.